# HTML/CSS - Problem with aligning elements in navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this simple website and right now I'm working on the navbar. In the navbar I also have this logo that I created with font awesome and text, it also has a bigger font size than the other elements in the navbar. My problem is that the logo text isn't aligning with all the other text in the navbar.

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px
}

body {
  background-color: RGB(40, 43, 48);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: RGB(30, 33, 36);
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-nav li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.main-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.push {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.nav-logo:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  height: 2px;
  top: 24px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.nav-logo:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: center;
}

nav-content {}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/df395811d0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#home" class="nav-logo"> <i class="fa-solid fa-greater-than fa-18px"></i> Terminalize </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#html" class="nav-contents"> HTML </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#CSS" class="nav-contents"> CSS </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="JavaScript" class="nav-contents"> JavaScript </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#python" class="nav-contents"> Python </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#windows" class="nav-contents"> Windows </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#linux" class="nav-contents"> Linux </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#macos" class="nav-contents"> MacOS </a> </li>
    <li class="nav-content push "> <a href="#about"> About </a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[What my navbar looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R58S.png)

Comment: Try adding a line-height, half the size of the logo font-size:  .nav-logo { line-height: 10px; } and see if this fits your styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just had to set **align-items: center** on your **main-nav** class, as shown below:

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px
}

body {
  background-color: RGB(40, 43, 48);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: RGB(30, 33, 36);
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-nav li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.main-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.push {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.nav-logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.nav-logo:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  height: 2px;
  top: 24px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.nav-logo:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: center;
}

nav-content {}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/df395811d0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#home" class="nav-logo"> <i class="fa-solid fa-greater-than fa-18px"></i> Terminalize </a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#html" class="nav-contents"> HTML </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#CSS" class="nav-contents"> CSS </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="JavaScript" class="nav-contents"> JavaScript </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#python" class="nav-contents"> Python </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#windows" class="nav-contents"> Windows </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#linux" class="nav-contents"> Linux </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#macos" class="nav-contents"> MacOS </a> </li>
    <li class="nav-content push "> <a href="#about"> About </a> </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```